# open/seekp/write is truncating file

Tags: c++, fstream

**Description:** I have a text file with a few lines in it and I want to write in between two lines.

**What I tried:** I have a loop that determines the position where i want to write. When I try to open the file use seekp to position the input and then write the file gets truncated.

**Example**

**file.txt:**

```
Hello
Write under this line
Write above this line
```

**Code:**

```
ofstream myfileo;
myfileo.open("file.txt");

cout<<myfileo.tellp()<<endl;//starts at 0

myfileo.seekp(26);//move to 26 ...End of second line
cout<<myfileo.tellp()<<endl;//says 26

string institution ="hello";
myfileo<<"\n"<<institution<<"\n";
myfileo.close();
```

**Problem:** I'm not sure why the file gets truncated. I tried using append but no matter what it writes to the bottom which makes since, but I am left unsure in what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,
JT

Comment: How do you know that the position to write to is 26?  You are opening the file in text mode, not binary mode.  So position 26 in a text file may not point to where you think it will be pointing to due to the CR/LF translation.

Comment: I think that this is how it is supposed to work. You need to read the lines after that point and write the new line with them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Point is its truncating the file. If that position turns out to be incorrect I can find my way around that issue. I just dont understand how I am suppose to write in between two lines without loading the entire life into memory and then outputting it back...Whats even the point of seekp then?

Comment: @HenryHu so your suggesting i would have to read in the entire file to do this?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, that's just how writing to a file works. Try to think about writing to a file as similar to typing with the *insert* key pressed (in overwrite mode) or overwriting the current contents of an array.

Comment: @jliv902 So the only way to accomplish this is loading the entire file in my program, making the changes, and then writing the entire file back? This seems grossly inefficient.

Comment: @tman There is no efficient way of doing this. You do not have to get the entire file though, just everything after where you want to write to.

Comment: @jliv902 exactly how are you suggesting I do this? I have tried appending the file and setting the input position and this didn't function. Could you give me a short run down of how you would accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do what I posted in the comments is possible but frustrating.
Here is code that works for this particular example, but doesn't work in all cases:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main (void)
{
    std::fstream file ;

    file.open ("test.txt") ;
    file.seekg (28, file.beg) ; // 28 was the correct offset on my system.

    auto begin = std::istream_iterator <std::string> (file) ;
    auto end = std::istream_iterator <std::string> () ;
    std::vector <std::string> buffer (begin, end) ;

    file.clear () ; // fail-bit is sometimes set for some reaon.
    file.seekg (28, file.beg) ;
    file << "\n" "hello" "\n" ;

    std::copy (std::begin (buffer), std::end (buffer), 
        std::ostream_iterator <std::string> (file, " ")) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

If you don't want to load everything into memory, a better solution would be to use a temporary file. Let's call it *temp.txt*. You would then:

1. Copy into *temp.txt* everything from *file.txt* before where you wish to insert text.
2. Insert the text you wish to insert into *temp.txt*.
3. Copy into *temp.txt* the rest of *file.txt*.
4. Delete *file.txt*.
5. Rename *temp.txt* to *file.txt*.

Steps 4 and 5 are OS specific (unless you have some portable library that can do this).